# Simple proof that $\lfloor \log_2 k \rfloor + 1 = \lceil \log_2 (k + 1) \rceil$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing, logarithms, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Is there any way to show for $k \in \mathbb{N}$ 
$$\lfloor \log_2 k \rfloor + 1 = \lceil \log_2 (k + 1) \rceil$$

without casework, or of little of it as possible? I've tested it for some integers and I noticed that both sides seem to "transition" at the same point-- when $k$ is around powers of $2$ - but I don't know if I can explain it elegantly.

Comment: This is just due to the fact that there is no natural number between $\log_2(k)$ and $\log_2(k+1)$. Indeed, if the contrary was the case, then $\log_2(k) < n < \log_2(k+1)$, which yields $k < 2^n < k+1$, which is impossible.

Comment: @amsmath 1) that is wrong. 2) comments are not the right place to post answers

Comment: @miracle173 Why is this wrong? And, of course, if something is very simple, you can well answer by comment.

Comment: @amsmath I think your answer is correct. It's really nice because I can just include it as an elegant one-liner in my paper, and let the reader think for it about a moment themselves rather than interrupting the flow with a proof.

Comment: I think with my argumentation you still need 3 cases. Therefore, I like Alexander's answer more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For $k\in\mathbb{N}$,
$$\left\lfloor\log_2 k\right\rfloor=m \iff 2^m\le k<2^{m+1} \iff 2^m<k+1\le 2^{m+1} \iff \left\lceil\log_2(k+1)\right\rceil=m+1.$$

Note that this works "for any value of $2$", i.e. for any integer base $b>1$, not just $2$.